# Pandas dataframe - COlumn visible but not available for operations

Tags: python, pandas

I am processing a daily stock quote file and converting to weekly/monthly data.the date column is visible when dataframe is printed but i cannot access the column- no operation can be performed on that column. I am getting a key error when trying to access the "date" column. Here is the snippet.

```
logic = {
         'Open'  : 'first',
         'High'  : 'max',
         'Low'   : 'min',
         'Close' : 'last',
         'Volume': 'sum'}
f=pd.read_csv("C://PathToFolder//test.csv",parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date'])
f=f.resample('W').apply(logic)
f.index-=to_offset("6D")
print(f.tail(1))
```

Result:
Open   High   Low  Close   Volume
Date
2022-01-31  79.25  81.35  75.8   76.0  2585556

If i add the following line then it throws keyerror:

```
f1=f[f['Date']>'2022-01-30']
```

Then i checked what columns are present in the df with the help of columns to list function:

```
print(f.columns.tolist())
```

`==> ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']`

The question is why is the date column visible if its not even there? I think i am missing something very simple. can anyone please guide

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'Date' is being used as your index because of `index_col=['Date']` in the read_csv() function call, hence you can't see it as a column. You might want to use `f.reset_index(inplace=True)` to get it back

Comment: Thanks for your comment. you helped me recover from 2 hours of search madness.